# Django app is not loading and giving IsADirectoryError error

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am new to django and python. I used a django theme to build a site. Djanog, NGINX, Gunicorn is working properly. Issue is when I try to load the page using app url, it gives me IsADirectoryError.
Below is all the infomation.

**Base Directory**

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 rwb  root 4096 Jul 30 15:43 netdash_venv/
drwxr-xr-x 3 rwb  root 4096 Aug  5 16:12 projects/core
```

**netdash_venv** is the python virtual folder and all the projects files are in **core** folder under **projects**.

```
:/opt/netdash/projects$ ll core
total 76
drwxrwxr-x 7 rwb rwb       4096 Aug 11 11:28 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 rwb root      4096 Aug  5 16:12 ../
drwxrwxr-x 4 rwb rwb       4096 Aug 10 16:30 app/
drwxrwxr-x 4 rwb rwb       4096 Aug  5 16:31 authentication/
drwxrwxr-x 5 rwb rwb       4096 Aug  5 16:17 core/
srwxrwxrwx 1 rwb www-data     0 Aug 11 11:28 core.sock=
-rw-r--r-- 1 rwb rwb      40960 Aug  5 16:39 db.sqlite3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 rwb rwb        624 Aug  5 15:36 manage.py*
drwxrwxr-x 4 rwb rwb       4096 Aug 10 16:00 sei/
drwxrwxr-x 4 rwb rwb       4096 Aug  5 15:48 staticfiles/
```

**app** and **authentication** app handles the authentication/login/logout parts. I am having issues launching sei app from the sidebar url.

**sidebar.html** file is in the **projects/core/core/templates/** folder.

```
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="sidebar-link" href="/sei">
            <span class="icon-holder">
              <i class="c-red-500 ti-video-camera"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="title">SEI</span>
          </a>
        </li>
```

When I click the href link above I get the following error.

```
IsADirectoryError at /sei/
[Errno 21] Is a directory: '/opt/netdash/projects/core/core/templates'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://******.net/sei/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: IsADirectoryError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 21] Is a directory: '/opt/netdash/projects/core/core/templates'
Exception Location: /opt/netdash/netdash_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loaders/filesystem.py in get_contents, line 23
Python Executable:  /opt/netdash/netdash_venv/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
['/opt/netdash/projects/core',
 '/opt/netdash/netdash_venv/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/opt/netdash/netdash_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
    'sei'
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "home"   # Route defined in app/urls.py
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "home"  # Route defined in app/urls.py
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "core/templates")  # ROOT dir for templates

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**core - urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),          # Django admin route 
    path("", include("authentication.urls")), # Auth routes - login / register
    path("", include("app.urls")),            # UI Kits Html files
    path("sei/", include("sei.urls")),
]
```

**app - urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from app import views

urlpatterns = [

    # The home page
    path('', views.index, name='home'),

    # Matches any html file
    re_path(r'^.*\.*', views.pages, name='pages'),
]
```

**app - views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django import template

# Create your views here.
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")

@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def pages(request):
    context = {}
    # All resource paths end in .html.
    # Pick out the html file name from the url. And load that template.
    load_template = request.path.split('/')[-1]
    html_template = loader.get_template( load_template )
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```

**sei - urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="sei"),
]
```

**sei - views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import camera

# Create your views here.
def index(request):

    cameras = camera.objects.all()

    return render(request, "sei.html", {'cameras': cameras})
```

I have tried multiple things. I can login and logout but whenever I tried to go to /sei, it gives me error. Please help.

Comment: Is it correct that your template path includes "core/core"?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Have you tried to re-order your core urls.py? Put the line for Sei second or first in the urlpatterns list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django checks the url against the urlpatterns list in the sequence that they are entered.

Your current **core - urls.py** looks like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),          # Django admin route 
    path("", include("authentication.urls")), # Auth routes - login / register
    path("", include("app.urls")),            # UI Kits Html files
    path("sei/", include("sei.urls")),
]
```

This means that the **app.urls** will be checked before the **sei.urls**.

I'm not a regex expert, but it seems like the "sei/" is matching your url for your **pages** view in **app**. It then tries to load **sei** as a template but can't because it's a directory ...  "IsADirectoryError at /sei/".

You can improve the regex by replacing it with **r'^/[^/]*.html'** so it only matches urls pointing to the root folder and ending in **.html**

I recommend re-ordering your urls so the more spesific ones are checked first.

**New core - urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),          # Django admin route 
    path("sei/", include("sei.urls")),
    path("", include("authentication.urls")), # Auth routes - login / register
    path("", include("app.urls")),            # UI Kits Html files
]
```

This way **sei/** will match first and load the correct view.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. When I put **path("sei/", include("sei.urls"))** first then it loads the page but two things happens. Page loses the theme icons that I am using and I can get to the sei page even without authenticating myself as **app.urls** is not checking @login_required any more. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I added @login_required to sei views.py as well. Now it checks the authentication as well. Only pain is I have to add to all new apps as well. But not a big deal. Only thing not working is SEI page loses the theme icon path. Your re-ordering solved my issue though.

Comment: Do you mean it's not loading the style sheet? If so it depends how you set it up. You probably need to add "../" to the path since you are now in the "sei/" directoy, one level up. Django supports serving static files, but that's a whole new question. If you are happy that my answer solves the original question, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: No it is not the style sheet. It is working. sei page is loading now. That is what I had issue with to begin with. Thanks for your help. I will mark it as accepted answer.